# Best approach to add mark at touch location in ImageView ( similar to google maps )

Tags: android

Basically what title say. I have an ImageView with an image inside. What would be the best way to add pins into an image ( similar to google maps where you add a pin to location ), then I want to save it and when I open an app I want it to show ( right location no matter of screen size ). Also, an image can have multiple pins on it ( pins can be different like a cross mark, circle,... does not really matter ). Also what is the best way to scale an image to fit any screen ( keep ratio ).

I've searched around for best practice but still confusing. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: you could create a custom view. Draw bitmap image on the canvas. Set touchlistener, from the motion event, get x, y positions of touch location. Draw pin there, save Btmap. Done.

Comment: Do you maybe know for an example online? Thank you.

Comment: Just google it. How to draw bitmap on canvas. There should be a lot of tutorials.

Comment: Ty. Yh  found it. Guess was search with wrong keywords.